# Can you please rename the zeppelin tags?

Tags: support, tagging

I'd like to request two tag renames:

[zeppelin](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeppelin) -> [openzeppelin](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openzeppelin)

[zeppelin-os](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeppelin-os) -> [zeppelinos](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeppelinos)

I want to add some common questions that we are getting in our channels to make them permanent and more easy to find, and then start redirecting people here to get a more sustainable relationship with our community. I think these renames will make this a little nicer.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting these :-) For the second one, in my opinion your suggestion is less clear, and reads like a single word, "Zeppelinos", (i.e. the plural of "Zeppelino", whatever that would be... A baby zeppelin? Not sure... ), rather than "Zeppelin OS". Happy to hear other people's opinions :-)

Comment: that's how the project is called: https://zeppelinos.org/ :)

Comment: I agree with this vision, I find "openzeppelin" tag more appropriate than just zeppelin. For the second proposition we can use both as synonym tag what do you think?.

Comment: That sounds nice.

Comment: But you don't say "Zeppelinos" but "Zeppelin O S", so the dash is appropriate here.

Comment: I think the dash will make it a little harder to find, because everywhere else it will be without a dash. But, I'm more interested on the zeppelin->openzeppelin rename; whatever you feel correct with respect with the dashes will be better than now.

Comment: Could you further define your proposal? There are libraries, like `openzeppelin-solidity`, `openzeppelin-zos`, and `zos-lib`, then there is the ZeppelinOS command line `zos`. Which are you proposing would end up where?

Comment: everything related to the OpenZeppelin package, including openzeppelin-zos and openzeppelin-solidity should be tagged 'openzeppelin'.
Everything related to ZeppelinOS, including zos and zos-lib should be tagged 'zeppelinos'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zeppelin is now OpenZeppelin, can we please rename the associated tags?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/zeppelin-is-now-openzeppelin-can-we-please-rename-the-associated-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Please name it  [open-zeppelin](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-zeppelin) (and make `zeppelin` a synonym) and keep  [zeppelin-os](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeppelin-os). Dashes are a useful separator and help your eyes to quickly recognize tags.