# Zeppelin is now OpenZeppelin, can we please rename the associated tags?

Tags: support

Zeppelin Solutions is now OpenZeppelin
https://blog.openzeppelin.com/openzeppelin-rebranding/

---

- OpenZeppelin is now OpenZeppelin Contracts
- ZeppelinOS is now OpenZeppelin SDK
- ZepKit is now OpenZeppelin Starter Kits
- Audits is now OpenZeppelin Security Audits

To match the new names, can we please rename the zeppelin tags:

- [zeppelin](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tags/zeppelin/info) => openzeppelin
- [open-zeppelin](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tags/open-zeppelin/info) => openzeppelin-contracts
- [zeppelin-os](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tags/zeppelin-os/info) => openzeppelin-sdk

Thanks

Andrew B Coathup
Community Manager
[OpenZeppelin](https://openzeppelin.com/)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag renames have been completed.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.